# Connect to remote DB through SSH in CakePHP

Tags: database, cakephp, ssh

I need to connect to a remote DB hosted in AWS from my local project with CakePHP under Windows, can't seem to find help on this, anyone have any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SSH tunnel. Please see [this article](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009887-access-your-database-remotely-through-an-ssh-tunnel).